# Not able to use Query with Dapper in Class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dapper

I am very new bee for Dapper ORM, i am just trying to create a class library for Business logic with Dapper. I have Install the Dapper into the class Library with Nuget. And i can see the reference in the references for Dapper(1.50.2). Now i write following code, in which i am not able to access "Query".

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class Class1
   {

    static IDbConnection db2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerConnString"].ConnectionString);
    public Class1()
    {
    }
    public List<dynamic> GetRecords()
    {
        string query = "select * from contacts";
        return (List<dynamic>)db2.Query<dynamic>(query);

    }
   }
}
```

Please help me.. and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you add `using Dapper;` on top?

Comment: @Jcl, ohh my goddddd what a silly mistake.. i made.. you are superman.. dude... please post this comment as answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the extensions on the `Dapper` namespace. Just add:

```
using Dapper;
```

On top of your file

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that, a more correct way to write the class

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    using Dapper;

    public class Class1 {
        private static readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerConnString"].ConnectionString;

        public Class1() {}

        public List<dynamic> GetRecords() {
            string query = "select * from contacts";
            using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                return db.Query<dynamic>(query).AsList();
        }
    }
}
```

This handles dispose of the `SqlConnection` object and `.AsList` method saves from typecasting `IEnumerable<>` to `List<>`.

Comment: good point.. actually, i am going to use "using".. but your point for typeCasting is very valid.. i really appreciate i.. +1 for this.

Comment: just want to confirm, you are talking about "ToList" as there is no "AsList()".. in framework 4.5

Comment: @RamSingh `.AsList()` is in Dapper and safe conversion to `List<>`. See the definition [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L417).

Comment: @Shreevardhan, ohk got it.. actually i was checking in application where i have dapper 1.38